# Nodejs - Using async.forEachOf to do a loop and return without a callback

Tags: node.js, async.js

I'm not making any calls to any server. *I'm simply looping over an object and making some simple comparisons on the current item.* I want to be able to use return instead of nesting my code inside a callback. By my current understanding of node.js, the below code should execute immediately and return the boolean.

Example:

```
function validate() {
  var error = false;
  var items = {
    'item1': 'value1',
    'item2': 'value2'
  };
  var eachItem = function(item, key, next) {
    // do some simple comparisons
    if (item !== 'value3') {error = true;}
    next();
  };
  async.forEachOf(items, eachItem, function() {
    // I prefer not to use callback(error), error is defined here
    console.log('End Validate', error);
    return error;
  });
}
var thisError = validate();
console.log('After Validate', thisError); // thisError is undefined
```

The above does not work. I'm thinking because I'm using `async.forEachOf`.  `validate()` is always `undefined`. However, when debugging, I notice that  the boolean is defined before the next code is ran ('End Validate' shows up, then 'After Validate' does, which is the correct order of execution). Looks like it's simply not returning. **Is there any way to return the boolean from the function in my above example without using a callback?**

I do not want to use a `for...in` because I love the way `async` references the current item in the collection, and if I never need to, I can easily change my code with a callback in case I'm actually doing async operations.

Comment: Is there a reason you are looping over the items asynchronously like that?

Comment: Personal preference and very little code refactoring if actual asynchronous requests are needed in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Habits. The answer turns out to be very simple. I needed to define the return as the last line in the `validate()` function. It cannot be inside the `async.forEachOf` method.

The below is a working example.

```
function validate() {
  var error = false;
  var items = {
    'item1': 'value1',
    'item2': 'value2'
  };
  var eachItem = function(item, key, next) {
    // do some simple comparisons
    if (item !== 'value3') {error = true;}
    next();
  };
  async.forEachOf(items, eachItem, function() {
    // I prefer not to use callback(error), error is defined here
    console.log('End Validate', error);
  });
  return error;
}
var thisError = validate();
console.log('After Validate', thisError); // thisError is defined
```